# How to repeat music by mciSendString in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Originally my code is like below:

```
mciSendString("play bgm.wav", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

However, I find that when the music is finished, it can not repeat. I try the

```
mciSendString("play bgm.wav repeat", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

as well, and it does not work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Check the device have which command line argument for repeat functionality.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I don't know what's your mean for checking the device...Sorry, I am new to c++.

Comment: bgm == background music?  Perhaps simpler to call [`PlaySound()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx) w/ SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/124185

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490552/mp3-playing-using-mci-send-string-c

Comment: @Sumeet, what does I try the mciSendString("play bgm.wav notify repeat", NULL, 0, hand); however, identifier hWnd is not defined....What does hWnd means? Someone told me that I need to include <windef.h> however, it still does not work.

Comment: hand is the HANDLE of CreateWindow. In your case I guess you have not created the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mciSendString("play mp3 wait repeat", NULL, 0, NULL);
```